# HTML barcode font in div tag

Tags: html, fonts, barcode

I do realize that to some this may sound like an incredibly stupid question but my brain's not functioning as it should be.
I'm trying to load and set a font (libre barcode 39, link below) inside a div. NOT in the <'head><'style>, but in the actual <'div> itself. Is such a thing possible?

Thanks a million in advance,
best,
Tim

Link to font:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39#standard-styles

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rule `font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39', sans-serif;` to inline style the div. Make sure to import the font with the `link` tag, otherwise the rendering might fallback to sans-serif.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+39&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39', sans-serif;">Hello</div>
```